# How to fix the Port 8080 error in Spring Tool Suit 4?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, maven, tomcat

**Please, how to change port 8080?**

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-21 19:03:11.350 ERROR 1632 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

Comment: Look at your system whio is using port 8080, kill the process and run yor mven script again

Answer (score 1):

You can either find out what process is using the port and kill it, or you can configure your app to use a different port. To configure the port that your app uses, put this in your application.properties:

`server.port=port_number_here`

So for example, to make your app use port 8081:

`server.port=8081`

Comment: Can you teach me this with screen print please? I'm new at this

Comment: I don't have access to an IDE with a Spring Boot project now, so unfortunately not. The file should be in /src/main/resources/application.properties inside your project. See [this tutorial](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-change-tomcat-port/).

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the quick response and help